# Trying to make a homogeneous phantom

Tags: medicine

I am making a T1 weighted phantom for an MRI project. It consists of distilled boiling water, 7g/L agar, 10g/L NaCl and 1g/L CuS04. As the phantom cools it will get a jelly like texture. What I would like is for the phantom to be as homogeneous as reasonably possible when it solidifies. What do you think is the best way to do so?

I was thinking of having the mixture on a vibrating plate, or maybe a centrifuge or even just inverting the mixture at regular intervals. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what a weighted phantom T1 is but having used soft agar I do know that 0.7% agar is extremely sloppy, sort of semi-solid. If it is present as a thin  layer on top of a standard 1.5% agar plate and you jerk the plate then the top layer will deform. This is with microbiology-grade agar, maybe less pure versions behave differently?

Comment: Hi Alan, that's from a recipe I saw before. But I've looked at other recipes and they say 2.3% which seems a lot more realistic! Thanks for confirming my suspicion!